# RichEdit Text Save to text File in RAD C++

Tags: richedit, richeditabletext

I want to save as text file Which is Text Lines in TRichEdit in RAD C++ how can I save My application RichEdit text in to save text file Thanks

Please help me to how to code this i RAD C++ Language I could able to write Lines of text to RichEdit and my requirement is open Save Dialog and save text in RichEdit to text file